# Why the exception handling is not checking existence of library

Tags: python, exception

I don't understand why python (at least 2.7) is not validating the exception handling mechanism for errors.

Example:

```
try:
    some code selecting data from pymongo
except pymongo.errors.OperationFailure:
    exception
```

In this case, if the exception is not called for the first time, python will not validate if I actually did import the pymongo lib.

Any idea why?

Comment: I don't quite get the question. Do you already have `import pymongo` somewhere? What is this try-except block trying to do and why it should "validate" pymongo's existence?

Comment: No, @kindall understood and answered me already. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm reading your question right, you want to know why `except pymongo.errors.OperationFailure` doesn't cause an error when the module is loaded if you haven't already imported the `pymongo` module.

Like most things in Python, the arguments to `except` clauses are evaluated at runtime. In fact, they can be expressions! Python does not validate them at "compile" time any more than it validates any other names at that time.

The reason is that Python is a dynamic language. Imports can be done conditionally, or performed based on names that are not known at "compile" time, and modules and other namespaces can be replaced, modified, or removed by code. As a result, Python literally cannot know whether `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure` is a valid name at that point in your code's execution without *running* your code.

Comment: `pylint` is a good tool to catch these sorts of problems, to the extent that you can do static analysis of code in a dynamic language.

Answer (score 1):

According to PyMongo documentation, exception `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure` will be "raised when a database operation fails". AS such, your `except`block gets evaluated only when such an error is raised.

I'm assuming that by "validation of pymongo's existence" you are referring to somethine like:

```
try:
   import pymongo
except:
   print("PyMongo not found!")
   sys.exit(-1)
```

This method is often used **to provide fallbacks (and backwards compatibity) not to "validate" imports**. For instance in the case of `json` encoder/decoder, we can try whether we have `simplejson` library available and use `json`library as a fallback as follows:

```
try:
   import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
   import json
```

Assuming that in the beginning of your script, you already have `import pymongo`, I don't see a reason why you should be checking or "validating" that pymongo has been imported: `import pymongo` will already raise an `ImportError` if `pymongo` library is not found.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **`pymongo.errors.OperationFailure` may be defined anywhere**, not only as a part of `pymongo` module, but also as a property of property of `pymongo` object defined in the same file.

Thus when handling exceptions **Python should not check if specific module has been imported**.

But if you do something like that:

```
import pymongo
```

you will see that **import error is actually raised if module is not found**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pymongo
ImportError: No module named pymongo
```

If my answer is not enough for you and you want to know more about why inclusion of `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure` does not throw any error when you run your script for the first time, even though you do not have any `import pymongo` statement in your code, then please see [kindall's answer on Python being a dynamic language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331267/why-the-exception-handling-is-not-checking-existence-of-library/8331349#8331349).